Low pass filter for AC mains
A few days ago, I posted about a problem with the power coming from the outlets at my apartment. I couldn't find a commercial solution, so I am now trying to design a low-pass filter for anything over 100Hz.
First, I created a schematic that replicated the issue as closely as possible to what I was seeing:

The result:

Then, I tried to design an RC low pass filter:

It removed the spike, but at each stage, it attenuated the voltage and shifted the phase:

Questions:

How can I drive a load that varies from 0-2000W and requires the original 110V?
Should I care about the phase shift?
Can I do it in a way that those resistors and capacitors stay small and do not have to dissipate the heat? I tried simulating with a transformer, but then I considered situations where the load might pull 10A, which at 110V would be a lot of power going through those resistors.
I looked at examples of MOSFETs driving AC loads but could never make the simulation work. Is it possible in this case?
Are there any other gotchas in this design?


You need an LC filter. What kind of budget are you expecting to spend on this? (The inductors will be large.)

Up to 1k usd if possible.

In days-gone-by, higher power line filtering (and stabilizing amplitude) was done with a ferroresonant transformer. Bulky and heavy, it was simple and fairly robust and used no active electronics.


I suggest just powering it directly from mains. Although power line filters do exist. You could try one.

Unlikely. But may depend for what you use the filter output. Phase shitft usually does not matter.

Technically by using very small resistor values, maybe in milliohms instead of megaohms, and scaling the capacitance accordingly. As you will see from the values, a mains RC filter for 2 kW power will be impractical. LC filter may fare better, but it might be very large.

We don't know what you tried. But many inverters use FETs to drive the mains AC. They usually are not linear amplifiers but D-class amplifiers that run on high frequency so it's easy to filter it so 50 Hz remains.

Other than being an unsuitable RC filter for 2 kW mains, there should be no other gotchas.



To confirm, for the inverter, do you mean something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25q9rOx28VI&ab_channel=ElectroAcademy where it essentially pulses at very high frequencies to achieve the pure sine wave? I am going to do a better research into it.
